# Bootstrap conflict causes small elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My overrides at the bottom seem to cause a conflict in the bootstrap.min.css files and result in my elements being very small as seen here:

http://all41web.co.za/bootstrap1/index_Auth.html

How do i keep both bootstrap.min.css but increase the element size to be bigger:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
<link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/grayscale.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: You’ve got a bunch of duplicates in there! `jquery-3.2.1` & `jquery-3.2.1.slim` are not meant to be used together. And you’ve got a CDN version of `bootstrap.min.css` as well as a local vendored one

Comment: i know...the problem is i need both...maybe not the jquery but the bootstrap i need them both, removing one causes problems in other areas of the site...i think in the end i just dont even know how to describe the problem except to say i need the elements bigger than they currently appear

Comment: “*I need both*” - then something’s wrong. Choose one to start with, and fix the problems with it by yourself instead of just layering libraries on top of each other until it looks okayish

Comment: ok i have removed the first one except there is now no spacing between the elements.

http://all41web.co.za/bootstrap1/index_Auth2.html
and the navbar items aren't as aligned as in 

http://all41web.co.za/bootstrap1/index_Auth.html

Comment: Okay, so try to fix that yourself. If you can’t, post a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: ok lets try this: whats the correct description of increasing element size.?
as seen here:

all41web.co.za/bootstrap1/index_Auth.html 

Then i will enter the right google search.
is it 'increase resolution' or 'element size'

Comment: These are not [mcve]s. If you want help on SO, you’ll need to strip down your code to the simplest form that reproduces your problem *and then post it in a new question*. If in doing so your code suddenly works, then great! If it doesn’t, then we can see exactly where the problem is and help you solve it.

Comment: lol alright MTCosta i will try and break it down into  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples, it will be a series of questions...please be this available to assist when i do...

Comment: Not my name ...

Comment: ive tried to post a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example please assist